# $ \int_{0}^{1}x^m.(1-x)^{15-m}dx$ where $m\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

$=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^m.(1-x)^{15-m}dx$ where $m\in \mathbb{N}$

My Try:: Put $x=\sin^2 \theta$ and $dx = 2\sin \theta.\cos \theta.d\theta$ and changing limit, We Get

$ = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2m}\theta.\cos^{30-2m}\theta.2\sin \theta.\cos \theta d\theta$

$ = \displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2m+1}\theta.\cos^{31-2m}\theta d\theta$

Now How can i proceed after that.

Is there is any method to Calculate the Given Integral Then plz explain here.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$f(m,n)=\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^ndx$$

Repeated partial integration on the right hand side reveals that:

$$(m+1)f(m,n)=n\,f(m+1,n-1)$$

$$(m+2)(m+1)f(m,n)=n(n-1)\,f(m+2,n-2)$$

$$\cdots$$

$$(m+n)\cdots (m+1)\,f(m,n)=n!\,f(m+n,0)$$

$$\text{i.e}$$

$$(m+n)!f(m,n)=n!\,m!\,f(m+n,0)$$

Since

$$f(m+n,0)=\int_0^1 t^{m+n}dt=\frac{1}{m+n+1}$$

We have:

$$f(m,n)=\frac{n!\,m!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Now simply let $n=15-m$

Answer (score 3):

The [$\beta$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is defined as $$\beta(m,n) = \int_0^1 x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1} dx = \dfrac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$ In your case, $$\int_0^1 x^{m+1-1}(1-x)^{16-m-1} dx = \beta(m+1,16-m) = \dfrac{\Gamma(m+1) \Gamma(16-m)}{\Gamma(17)} = \dfrac{m! (15-m)!}{16!}$$

Comment: Thanks Marvis for Giving me a Nice solution. But Would You like to explain me without Using Gamma function. bcz Gamma function is Not Included in My Course. Thanks

Comment: @juantheron, look at the other answer.